# Last edited by tag?

Tags: tags, entry, edit-date

I have a report area on an EE site that shows specifics about entries in a channel, and was wondering if there was a way to show who edited that entry last? I am using the {edit_date format="%m-%d-%Y} to get the date/time it was modified, but it would be nice to know which user modified the entry. We have numerous backend admins with various priv's to maintain things.

Answer (score 2):

EECMS just saves the IP of who edited an entry, not his or her `member_id`.

You can try the Audit add-ons:

- [Audit Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit-pro), which lets you archive logged data, set custom email notifications and search log entries;
- [Audit Tags](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit-tags), which lets you output Audit’s logged data in your templates.

The add-on can be found on [github](https://github.com/Clearbold/audit-pro) as well.